# Django view return data

Tags: django

I have a view that returns an `HTML response` using `render`. The data returned is specific to a template.

If I want to consume that data on another page, should I write another view with the same logic, or is there a way to pass the data from view 1 to view 2

**view**
`return render(request, 'pages/project_details.html', {"project": project,`

**urls**
`path('show_project_details/<project_id>', view=show_project_details, name="show_project_details"),`

I know that a `view` is just a function, which takes a request and does something with it, but I don't get how I make a request to a view within a template and consume the response within an existing page.

Example here:

```
## filename: views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Team

def index(request):
    list_teams = Team.objects.filter(team_level__exact="U09")
    context = {'youngest_teams': list_teams}
    return render(request, '/best/index.html', context)
```

I want to return the data within this `context` to `home.html` and `index.html`.

Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your **urls.py** to pass a variables through via the URL notation.

*For example -* Getting Team info:

**template**

```
{% for team in youngest_teams %}
    <a href="{% url 'get_team_info' team.id %}">Team</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**url.py**

```
path('team_info/<team_id>', view=team_info, name="get_team_info")
```

**views.py**

```
def team_info(request, team_id=None):
    team = Team.objects.get(id=team_id) #Information on team is passed.
```

Comment: Thanks Lewis. So will `team` be returned to the template without having to specify `return` something?

Comment: @JacksWastedLife Lewis code is incomplete in views.py. You have to use your own logic and return the data through context to templates.

Comment: right, so i still need to `return (request, {"team":team}` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use that code but you have to return to multiple templates.

Comment: But I think your code has some issues because in the URL you are using id but in the views.py you are not using any id. It will create an error when you run the code.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by a return to multiple templates? So i still need to return `render` or just `return (request, template1, template2 {"team":team}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240602/discussion-between-huzaifa-zahoor-and-jackswastedlife).

Comment: If you want to use the same data on the two different templates, you have to use different URLs. Then the easy way is this, make other views in the views.py. It's easy way.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple cases in your case. Let me explain them one by one.
Let's say you have two templates. One is template 1 and the other is template 2.

1. If you want to use the same logic for template 1 and template 2. You can use a variable in the views.py & url.py and use a condition there on that variable which is team_id in your case. E.g.

```
def index(request, team_id):
    list_teams = Team.objects.filter(team_level__exact="U09")
    context = {'youngest_teams': list_teams}
    if team_id == 1:
         return render(request, '/best/index.html', context)
    elif: team_id == 2:
         return render(request, '/best/template2.html', context)
```

And in urls.py, you can write:

```
path('team_info/<int:team_id>', view=team_info, name="get_team_info")
```

2. If you don't want the variable in the views and URLs. Then you can write different views with the same code in views.py. But in the case of multiple ids, it will cause code duplication.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Huzaifa. I want the same data on both templates. so i need to write the same view for each template?

Comment: Yes, the easy way is that, use different views with the same code. But you can also make a function with the code and in different views, use same function and return the context to different templates.